# Do I outsmart SQL Server or there is a reason for this?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, group-by

I have the following tables

```
CREATE TABLE Foos (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY,
    -- Other fields
)

CREATE TABLE Boos (
    [Id] INT IDENTITY,
    [FooId] INT,
    -- Other fields
)
```

I am trying to execute a very simple query:

```
SELECT f.Id, COUNT(*)
FROM Foos f
JOIN Boos b on f.Id = b.FooId
GROUP BY b.FooId
```

Obviously I am getting an error because of the `GROUP BY`. The error message is

> Column 'Foo.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

When I change the group by to `GROUP BY f.Id` everything works fine again.

My question is, why would SQL Server throw that error while it already knows for sure that `f.Id = b.FooId` from the join, that `Foo.Id` is unique from the `IDENTITY`, and that the grouping will logically return the same count due to the join on a primary key?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is just the complexity of implementing this accurately and accounting for all situations. It is easier for SQl-Server to just be very rigid with it's rules. The SQL-Standard allows columns to be in the select and not in the group by or in an aggregate if they are functionally dependent on a column within the group by. PostgreSQL is the closest DBMS to implementing this accurately, but it still doesn't fully implement the standard (e.g your query fails, but you could include all columns from Foos if you group by f.ID - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/b420c/3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server cannot consistently reason about such key relationships - if boos.FooId is nullable and your query is:

```
SELECT f.Id, COUNT(*)
FROM Foos f
  LEFT JOIN Boos b on f.Id = b.FooId
GROUP BY b.FooId
```

you have a set of records where b.fooId is NULL and f.Id can be different between them.

You can also join on other conditions which may also cause NULLS or other sorts of non-equivalence - e.g. you could join like:

```
SELECT f.Id, COUNT(*)
FROM Foos f
  JOIN Boos b on SUBSTRING(f.Id, 2, 4) = SUBSTRING(b.FooId, 2, 4)
GROUP BY b.FooId
```

So - yes this can be reasoned about in one simple, common case, but only in that case. That would cause inconsistency, and ultimately prove more frustrating to developers.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server simply doesn't take these facts into account and therefore it can't infer that `b.FooId` will always be the same as `f.Id` in this particular query.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the result you expect to see is two columns of data, like:

```
ID   COUNT(*)
--   --------
 2          7
 3          2
 4         13
```

The SQL engine needs something to display in the ID column and you must explicitly tell it what that grouping / display item is.  The engine won't infer what you want to see.

This would be particularly important if you were doing an outer join where there were no records in Boos for a record in Foos.  In that case the engine needs to know which ID to display next to the count of zero.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to    give you below advise on usage of group by clause

Standard group by and having queries
All group by and having queries in the Examples section adhere to the SQL standard, which dictates that queries using group by, having, and vector aggregate functions produce one row and one summary value per group, using these guidelines:

Columns in a select list must also be in the group by expression, or they must be arguments of aggregate functions.

A group by expression can contain only column names that are in the select list. However, columns used only as arguments of aggregate functions in the select list do not qualify.

Columns in a having expression must be single-valued—arguments of aggregates, for instance—and they must be in the select list or group by clause. Queries with a select list aggregate and a having clause must have a group by clause. If you omit the group by for a query without a select list aggregate, all the rows not excluded by the where clause are considered to be a single group.

In nongrouped queries, the principle that “where excludes rows” seems straightforward. In grouped queries, the principle expands to “where excludes rows before group by, and having excludes rows from the display of results.”

The SQL standard allows queries that join two or more tables to use group by and having, if they also adhere to the above guidelines. When specifying joins or other complex queries, use the standard syntax of group by and having until you fully comprehend the effect of the Transact-SQL extensions to both clauses.

To help you avoid problems with extensions, Adaptive Server provides the fipsflagger option to the set command that issues a nonfatal warning for each occurrence of a Transact-SQL extension in a query. See set for more information.

Now in first scenario group by usage is invalid but in second case it is not.

Thanks
Niraj Rathi

Comment: *Columns in a select list must also be in the group by expression, or they must be arguments of aggregate functions.*, This certainly was true at one point, however since the 2003 Standard columns can be contained in the select list and not in the group by or within an aggregate function as long as they are functionally dependent on a column contained within the group by.

Answer (score 0):

You would still need to apply the appropriate grouping as you define in the original select statement `Select f.Id...` so you need to group by this column. You did not outsmart sql server.

Comment: because they are from different tables and cannot guarantee that the same id's will be present. If b.FooId was a foreign key then maybe it would be different, but there is no definition that suggests this.

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier and faster for SQL Server to check your query in traditional way, than make sure that:

- `b.FooId` in GROUP BY clause is really the same as `f.Id` in SELECT clause
- they are not null
- join is inner, not outer